# Curl command for authorization code

Tags: curl, authorization

Can anyone help me to find the answer for this question. In authorization grant type how to get the authorization code using curl command

Answer (score 2):

The Authorization Code grant type was specifically designed to work with full-blown User Agents (read: browsers). Reverse engineering such a flow in cURL is discouraged. It would miss the point of getting user consent and making the authentication method independent from the Client. One should rather use a different flow with cURL such as the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type or the Client Credentials grant type.

Comment: Thank you Hans. But in authorization code grant type it allows to get the access token using curl command. Then why only restrict to get the authorization code. Could you give me a detail description or any link to understand this?

Comment: thank you Hans. I have got it now. To get authorization code there must be a user agent (browsers). User agents will give the authorization code to the clients. Then only clients can get access token.

Answer (score 0):

**Request:**

curl -I -H "Authorization: Uploadcare.Simple demopublickey:demoprivatekey" \
     -X DELETE \
     "https://api.uploadcare.com/files/03ccf9ab-f266-43fb-973d-a6529c55c2ae/storage/"

**Response:**

HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://uploadcare.com
Allow: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 31 Aug 2014 21:00:51 GMT
Location: https://api.uploadcare.com/files/03ccf9ab-f266-43fb-973d-a6529c55c2ae/
Content-Length: 0